# Hide form values

Tags: asp.net, exception, elmah

I'd like to use *Elmah* on my website except I'm concerned that if I get an exception on a page that accepts credit card numbers then people's credit card numbers will end up in the error log. Of course, I don't want a copy of them anywhere on my server.

So is it possible to hide the value of a form field on a particular page? For example, it would appear as `txtBxCCNumber=xxxxxxxxxxxx` in the `Server Variable` section.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you [secure your Elmah logs](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages) from anonymous access.

Then, read the [section on Error Filtering](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering) and the [provided examples](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFilterExamples). You should be able to adapt an example on the page to filter out errors on your credit card form page.

Comment: Hi @peter, thanks for your reply. Sorry if its not clear but this question is specifically about logs created by Elmah. http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: Revised my post with new links :)

Comment: Ahh.. but I don't want to filter out errors. On the contrary, if there's an error when people are trying to pay then I want to know about it! I just want to change what gets written to the log.

Comment: Read the [page on programmatic filtering](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering). You may be able to write your own custom error handler for that page that filters out the sensitive variables.